# Building over the trained model after loosing the whole dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have trained an image classifier as explained in the [tensorflow documentation to train a model](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retraining). I have the output graph file `(output_graph.pb)`

Now, how could I build over this graph file? The problem is that I have lost the whole dataset and only left with the output graph file. I do not want to go through the whole process of collecting data and tuning it. I want to build over the current model with a new kind of data. Is there a way out?